# plotting json data in google map in android

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have the code to display google map current location as well as the code to parse json data. i want to know where will i merge the below code to plot json data in map.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String value1 = jsonobject.getString("Key1");
    String value2 = jsonobject.getString("Key2");
}
```

or is there some other way to plot json data to google map

Answer (score 0):

First initialise GoogleMap Object you can do whatever you want with Map.

```
   mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment_id))
                        .getMap();
if(mMap != null )
{
 //here play with mMap object however you want.
}
```

OR, if map object is already initialised, then just validate both location and json data then do that

Comment: please suggest me edit @M D, so that I may improve my solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same thing too

Map Code

```
 gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment_id))
                    .getMap();
        if(gMap != null )
        {


                 gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition,10));
                 final Marker myLocation=gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.position(myPosition).title("Your Location").snippet(Shared.mTotalMembers[39]).snippet(Shared.DataOnMap))



        }
```

Your JSON CODE

```
 JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
   String value1 = jsonobject.getString("Key1");
   String value2 = jsonobject.getString("Key2");
  }
 Shared.DataOnMap=value1+value2;
```